# dynamically changing custom html values using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div data-react-class="Duration" data-react-props="{"startDate":"","endDate":""}">
```

I have this in my html. How can I change the `startDate` and `endDate` values in `data-react-props` using jquery?

Comment: Is it running allright? Because your "{"startDate" should break (wrong "). Well, for changing these values with jQuery, maybe a simple var element = $('selector'); // var data = element.data('react-props'); // data['startDate'] = new value; // element.data('react-props', data); // that should do

Comment: it is created by react-rails helper and its working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery data selectors

```
$("div[data-react-class='duration']").attr("data-react-props","{'startDate':'12-12-2017', 'endDate':'01-01-2018'}");
```

Answer (score 2):

add an `ID` to the `div`:

```
<div id="sample" data-react-class="Duration" data-react-props="{"startDate":"","endDate":""}">
```

And use the `setAttribute` method:

```
document.getElementsByID('sample').setAttribute('data-react-props', '{"startDate":"","endDate":""}');
```